# Axially Symmetric Lens Integration

Tags: gravitational-lensing

I'm trying to understand the deflection of light due to an axially symmetric gravitational lens following chapter 2.3 of [these Heidelberg lecture notes](http://www.ita.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Emassimo/sub/Lectures/gl_all.pdf). In doing so, I encounter the integral (2.12 a)

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{r - r'\cos(\phi)}{r^2 + r'^2 - 2rr'\cos(\phi)}\,d\phi$$

which apparently vanishes for $r'>r$ and is $2\pi/r$ for $r'<r$. I've tried to understand how this answer comes about, but to no avail. I couldn't find it in an integral table and I can't get Mathematica to give me a useful answer unless I plug in specific values for $r,r'$.

Comment: where is the integral? could you maybe state the eqn no? what are $r$,$r'$, $\phi$?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. The integral is the first in equation 2.12. $\phi$ is the polar angle, $r,r'$ are non-negative constants.

Comment: I have the solution..sry can't type now...check plot...try recursion for vanishing...diff under sign for finite val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$I(r_0,r;a,b)=\int_a^{b}\frac{r_0-r \cos\phi}{r_0^2+r^2-2 r_0 r \cos\phi}d\phi$$

The integrand plots like

[image: plot of integrand]

Note that

$$
I(r_0,r;0,2\pi)=I(r_0,r;0,\pi)+I(r_0,r;\pi,2\pi) $$
Upon the change of varibale $\phi\to\phi-\pi$ in the second integral above, and then explicitly simplifying, one gets the recursion

$$
\begin{align}
I(r_0,r;0,2\pi)&=r_0\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{r_0^2-r^2 \cos\phi}{r_0^4+r^4-2 r_0^2 r^2 \cos\phi}d\phi \\
&=r_0~I(r_0^2,r^2;0,2\pi)\\
\end{align}
$$

Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
I(r_0,r;0,2\pi)&=\lim_{k\to\infty}r_0^{k -1}I(r_0^k,r^k;0,2\pi)\hspace{1cm} k\in1,2,4,8\ldots
\end{align}
$$

For $r<r_0$,
$$
\begin{align}
I(r_0,r;0,2\pi)&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{r_0^{k-1} r_0^k}{r_0^{2k}}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-(r/r_0)^k\cos\phi}{1+(r/r_0)^{2k}-2(r/r_0)^k\cos\phi}d\phi \\
&=\frac{2\pi}{r_0}
\end{align}
$$

For $r_0<r$,
$$
\begin{align}
I(r_0,r;0,2\pi)&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{r_0^{k-1} r^k}{r^{2k}}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(r_0/r)^k-\cos\phi}{1+(r_0/r)^{2k}-2(r_0/r)^k\cos\phi}d\phi \\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}(r_0/r)^{k-1}\ldots\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$

---